# What could be causing the rapid loss of tyre pressure?

Tags: tires, pressure, clio

I had a slow puncture a while ago and got the tyre replaced on my Renault Clio because it was bulging and non salvageable.

Since then I've been losing pressure in that tyre fairly rapidly.

I've had the tyre resealed 3 times now and I'm still losing pressure in the tyre (from full to flat in ~3 days even with no driving being done).

What else could be the cause? I'd rather not shell out for a new wheel and the mechanics say they don't know what's wrong with it.

Comment: Did they replace the valve when they replaced the tyre? If not, and if the leak started when the tyre was replaced, that's the first thing I'd check.

Comment: Thanks, I'll ask them. It's only started (or at least been significantly more obvious) since the tyre was replaced.

Comment: @TMN... I called and asked them, records say it's been replaced and they've checked the valve. Going to drop it into the garage to take another look as it's becoming pretty undriveable. Shame it's dark so early now as I'd like to do the soapy water test.

Comment: Sounds like a customer service issue. They need to refund it or repair it. If they are unable to do so, have it repaired at another shop, and then send the original mechanics the bill and reverse charges if you paid via credit card, or use whatever other consumer protection you have available in your jurisdiction for shops that do a lousy job.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Obviously, this can be anything.

- leak in the new tire
- even a leak in the rim
- leak between tire and rim (may be there's some dirt on the rim or a burr on the tire)
- leak between rim and valve stud
- leaky valve itself

You can do a soapsuds test (dish liquid water mixture) to find the leakage.

Comment: I found it was easier to just dismount the tire, fill the bathtub with water and stick the tire in it. It was pretty obvious where the leak was (there was a steady stream of small bubbles coming from the spot).

Comment: Yeah I can't take the tyre off without the garage doing it as it being put back on with the air compressor it's too tight for me to get off with the tyre iron (bends the iron without actually loosening the nuts)

Comment: @Ilessa: I'd complain pretty loudly to the garage, as that's a safety issue. You can't take a chance on being stuck in the middle of nowhere with a flat because some lazy mechanic can't be bothered to correctly torque your lug nuts.

Comment: I recall a family members car having to have the whole wheel mount replaced as the garage had put the nuts on too tightly, and the bolt sheared off when said family member attempted to remove the wheel.  I second @TMN's comment about complaining.

Comment: Thanks, turns out it was the wheel that was borked, so now have to find a new alloy. eep.

Answer (score 3):

If your rim is defective it can cause this. It could have a hole in it somewhere (welds and valve stem). If it is malformed it will lose pressure due to improper sealing. The malformation of the rim may be so subtle that it takes a while to lose pressure. 
From what you say I would assume the rim is defective. Lets not forget that just because the tire is new does not mean they can't be defective as well. "New" does not mean much because anything can be defective new or not. 
There are several tests you could do to see where it is leaking.

Get a spray bottle with a fine mist and spray around where your rim and tire mate. You'll have to watch very closely to see bubbles and listen for hissing. 
You can also fill the tire with a fine dye and observer where the leak is. 
other than that, you'll have to replace your tire and wheel to be absolutely sure you resolve the issue.